# Are relative package names possible in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have the following manifest (snippet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    package="com.uniquename.appname">

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".activity.MainApplication">
    ....
```

where `MainApplication.java` lives in `com.uniquename.appname.activity`

Yet, when I launch this, I get the following error:

> 10-10 23:12:33.327: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7783): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.uniquename.appname.MainApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.uniquename.appname.MainApplication in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar:/data/app/com.uniquename.appname-1.apk]

which strikes me as odd, as I've explicitly asked it to look in the activity sub package.  I've seen examples of others using this relative technique, yet it isn't working for me.  What's wrong with my declaration?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dang, always the case that you spend hours trying to figure it out, finally give up and ask the community and then 2 seconds later discover the answer.  In my case, the answer is, yes, it is possible to use relative paths in the manifest.xml file.  My problems stemmed from a large refactoring exercise which worked fine except that I forgot to update a few custom package names in my xml files (ticking 'Update fully qualified package names in non-java files' would have helped!).

Anyway, these now-out-of-date package references caused the failure at runtime.  Unfortunately, the error message you get is misleading and for me had nothing to do with my manifest declaration at all.  Fixing the package names in my xml files (without touching my manifest) solved the issue for me.  Hope this helps someone else some day.